Aggregating over multiple series and time in Prometheus PromQL
I have some data I am querying from Prometheus,  a range vector, that I am currently getting via sum by (label1, label2) (series_name), and as expected, it gives me the most recent results of the sums by the labels. I am trying to change it to get the results over a timeframe (let's say 1 minute with a resolution of 5 seconds).
I've tried to use sum_over_time by (label1, label2) (series_name[1m]) but aggregating with by doesn't seem supported by aggregation over time, so it just says that by was unexpected.

It depends on what you are doing. If you are using api, you should use /api/v1/query_range instead of /api/v1/query. If you use Grafana you'll need to either switch panel type, or change mode of query from Instant to Range in Query options. If you simply using web console of Prmetheus, you can either switch to graph tab, or use query like (sum by (label1, label2) (series_name)) [1m:5s]

And if 'to get the results over a timeframe' means not to get list of results, but get aggregated result over described time range, than what dganesh2002 wrote.

First create new series over time and then use aggregation sum by like this
sum by (cpu, instance) (sum_over_time(node_cpu[10m]))

Sorry, I meant to do what markalex wrote, but thanks for the reply anyways!
